# Why AntiForgeryToken in different browser tabs with different values all execute successfully?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have a form my MVC 5 View with antiforgery token.

I opened the same URL in 2 different tabs and looking at the page source code
I get 2 different __RequestVerificationToken form tokens.

The __RequestVerificationToken cookie has the same value.

First browser tab:

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
value="JK3VfUNG8MbkWHRcUUoYoYuBEqYg1VZl38rT_Oje6WRpUHIKnRgVsaXX6K_qQMm5OXiw5UDjKlSppYBeEFZbvzKHCDndo_BXcZYkcnxL9E1" />`

Second browser tab:

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="TFwq8uATFit48n63lm8AkWFw2uPCaAroIFYcjznF35tEbRc1vTyJaz3QDu4E_aIM85LcttBubeRqvxy-he0SMRQsTdtJwvvwQ_Adk1yWbVA1" />`

Clearly the form antiforgery tokens must be verified along with the antiforgery cookie.

But the form antiforgery tokens are different even though the antiforgery cookies are the same.

How can both pages upon POST execute successfully? How does the decryption work here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [Why does @Html.AntiForgeryToken() generate different tokens in same response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478392/why-does-html-antiforgerytoken-generate-different-tokens-in-same-response/27199139#27199139)

Comment: These are 2 separate responses because I opened the same URL in 2 different browser tabs

Comment: Did you read the answers in the link? (not sure what your comment is relating to - it makes no difference)

Comment: Sorry I will read your link now

Comment: @StephenMuecke So the reason for the difference is in the token's `AdditionalData`?

Comment: Essentially yes (although its a bit more complex than just that) - the method creates a unique token each time `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is called

Answer (score 0):

The browser generates the token based on the site's identifier and the cookie contains the key to decyrpt. As long as the site remains same "myapp.myserver.com", the browser will be able to decrypt the value. Browser just takes the successful decryption and hence validates the token.
ValidationResult = (Token + cookie = match)
Any number of time, the token can be generated and the browser can validate it belongs to a given site by using the cookie against it.

Comment: How would you explain when the form tokens are different and they still get validated correctly?

Comment: So if a hacker steals the cookie and somehow got hold of any of the previous tokens and do a POST and he will be granted access to the page?