# AntiforgeryToken works for one form and fails for 2nd form in partialview MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

So I have a `partialview` and I have 2 forms inside it as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAlbum", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "frmAlbumAdd", novalidate = "novalidate", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!--some controls and submit button-->
}
.....
.....
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImages", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "frmUploadImages", novalidate = "novalidate", autocomplete = "off", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!--some controls and submit button-->
}
```

and I am doing `ajax post` to the `Admin controller` as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]//This works well
public JsonResult AddAlbum(AlbumDataModel model)
{
    //perform some task and return result
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]//This results in Error
public JsonResult UploadImages([Bind(Prefix = "UIAModel")] UploadImageAlbum model)
{
    //perform some task and return result
}
```

and the error I get on second form submission is **"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present."**

According to this **[post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887983/if-i-add-multiple-forms-in-a-single-page-do-i-need-to-add-separate-anti-forgery)** we can have `antiforgerytokens` for different `forms` individually. But am not sure why this turns out to be error.

I've also tried adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the `Layout` where `partialviews` load and excluded it from `forms` and had below `ajaxSetup` to send `AntiForgeryToken` but even that didn't work.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var verificationToken = $("meta[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").attr('content');
    if (verificationToken) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Request-Verification-Token", verificationToken);
    }
});
```

How can I overcome this issue? What is actually happening here?

---

**UPDATE:**

I am using `ajax` to post the `formdata` to `controller` as below:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (data) {

      }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the javascript that creates the ajax requests?

Comment: @RobbertBrussaard.. Updated question. Please check and let me know...

Comment: How are you generating the value of `formdata`? If you use `var formdata = new FormData($('#frmUploadImages').get(0));` then everything including the token is serialized and you do not need you `$.ajaxPrefilter()` function (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for more detail)

Comment: And have you checked what `var verificationToken = $("meta[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").attr('content');` actually returns? - I suspect its `undefined`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Its working fine.. haven't tried with `formdata` even though was aware of to use `formdata` while posting the `image`.. Can you please post it as answer?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please post an answer to this.. :)

Comment: Hmm, must of missed your previous message. Need some sleep, but will do so in the morning  :)

Comment: Sure buddy.. No probs.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` generates a hidden input with `name="__RequestVerificationToken"` so to get the value you need (for the first form)

```
var verificationToken = $('#frmAlbumAdd [name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
```

and then you can append it to the `FormData` object using

```
formData.append('__RequestVerificationToken', verificationToken);
```

However, since you are using `FormData`, you can simply serialize all the form controls, including the token and file inputs using

```
var formdata = new FormData($('#frmAlbumAdd').get(0));
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest that you try the following:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
               //your implementation
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            },
            complete: function () {
               //your implementation
            }
        });
    });
```

This does not uses json as the datatype. Do you really need to use json i like you to take a look at this [How can i supply an AntiForgeryToken when posting JSON data using $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906754/how-can-i-supply-an-antiforgerytoken-when-posting-json-data-using-ajax)

Comment: As of my knowledge, `dataType` is to basically consider what type of data we receive from server. But this issue is on sending part. I hope it will not effect much. Still let me give a try and let you know..