# How to setup jQuery Ajax calls to inject an AntiForgeryToken globally in thair request header in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I works on an `Asp.net MVC 5` project and
know there is 2 way to pass the `AntiForgeryToken` to the server in `ajax` calls:

- Put it in `Header`
- Put it in `Data`

> I like putting `AntiForgeryToken` in `request header` and my codes
>   works well both client and server side. I followed [this article](https://richiban.uk/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/).

I put the `AntiForgeryToken` in each `$.ajax` call `header` and it works nice

**But**

Now i *decided* write new codes to add `AntiForgeryToken` to all `Ajax` calls that have `POST` type in my page globally and remove the header setting in each `$.ajax` block of codes.

Then i wrote this codes to implement my decision and **it works well** too when i have *one form* in my page (i did not test it in complected cases such as multiple forms in a page and...):

```
var antiForgerytoken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXhr) {
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() == "POST") {
        jqXhr.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", antiForgerytoken);
    }
});
```

**My questions:**

1. Has this decision any **security or inappropriate side effect**?
2. When i have **several form** in my page that each one created by a **different partial view and will handle by different actions in different controllers** should i find the related `AntiForgeryToken` in each form and inject it to all Ajax calls that are related to that form? **Or** just above codes is enough?

Maybe base of this question is another question that wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887983/if-i-add-multiple-forms-in-a-single-page-do-i-need-to-add-separate-anti-forgery) and [@DarinDimitrov answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887983/if-i-add-multiple-forms-in-a-single-page-do-i-need-to-add-separate-anti-forgery#5889120) include this description:

> `ASP.NET MVC` will simply reuse the **same value for all forms** so it doesn't need to know which form sent the request in order to validate it

*Is this rule is absolute? do you know any reference? I saw some opposite view in comments of @DarinDimitrov answer*

3. If i should behavior with each form `AntiForgeryToken` separately, how should i change the above codes to set `AntiForgeryToken` in Ajax header globally to work with all forms that rendered in a `MVC` page?